# Slash Command "Echo" Command Discord.JS

Tags: node.js, discord.js, slash

What I want the command to do is to say what we want the bot to say.

Example : */echo Testing* 
and the bot should respond : Testing

But I can't figure out how to do it

Here is my code :

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, SlashCommandStringOption } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('echo')
        .setDescription('Replies with your input!')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('input')
                .setDescription('The input to echo back')
                .setRequired(true)),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.send(input)
    },
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the [`CommandInteraction.options`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=options) and use [`.getString()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver?scrollTo=getString) on that to get the input

```js
async execute(interaction) {
    const input = interaction.options.getString("input")
    await interaction.reply(input)
}
```